# Kubernetes create an endpoint with DNS instead IP

Tags: kubernetes

I need to create an endpoint with DNS instead of IP

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
      nodePort: 30004
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: my-service 
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: **111.111.111.111** ** < need change this to DNS
    ports:
      - port: 5432
```

Everything works fine with numerical IP, but I need to put my Postgres DNS instead, something like:

```
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: mypostgres.com
    ports:
      - port: 5432
```

But "addresses" only support numerical IP. I need some workaround to make this work.

Comment: Try using https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/endpoint-slices/ and let me know if it solves your problem ot if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to connect to a remotely hosted database URI instead of IP you can use **ExternalName**

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: mongo
spec:
 type: ExternalName
 externalName: ds149763.mlab.com
```

Please check out more : https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services

Comment: Already tested it, but I need to use my kubernetes cluster as a router from an external application. My kubernetes cluster have access to my Postgres but my application don't, I need to access my Postgres from my application.

Comment: @LuizBuffa Did you find any solution for this?